# Bucle utilizando PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Buenas adjunto mi duda, en una imagen, ya que creo que se vera mejor.

Un saludo
[image: duda con un bucle utilizando PHPExcel]

EDITO:

El orden de las Acciones de los clientes no siempre sera así, me explico
Puede ser que El cliente Pedro Venda, luego Compra, luego Venda ... etc

Y al insertarlo en el excel solo rellenaria solo la 1º Compra con la fecha y hora de la susodicha compra.

Comment: ya revisaste [ask] es importante.

Comment: A qué te refieres¿?
Creo que se entiende, si la persona esta familiarizada con PHPExcel :s

Comment: ¿La duda es como ordenarlo o como generar el excel con PHPExcel?

Comment: como ordenarlo, osea a la hora de hacer el bucle, lo siento por no contestarte antes.

Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Para recorrer el bucle horizontalmente, ordena los datos segun el formato que necesitas.

Considerando que esta es tu respuesta de Base de Datos:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

Lo ideal seria que la base de Datos lo filtre por `Accion='Compra'`, en todo caso este codigo seleccionara solo los de `Accion='Compra'`:

```
//los datos selecccionado se almacenan en "$rowLimpia"
$rowLimpia = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($row);$i++){
    if($row[$i]["Accion"]=="Compra"){
        array_push($rowLimpia,$row[$i]);
    }
}
```

Ahora a ordenar Horizontalmente:

```
//Los datos ordenados estaran en "$data"
$data = array();
$datahijo = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($rowLimpia);$i++){
    //comparando "Id" de la fila actual con la anterior, si es diferente indica que se esta cambiando a los registro del siguente Cliente.
    if($rowLimpia[$i]["Id"]==@$rowLimpia[($i-1)]["Id"]){
        $datahijo[$contadorCompra."_Compra"] = $rowLimpia[$i]['Fecha'];
    }else{//Cuando es el siguiente Cliente...
        //... se agrega el Cliente anterior al array $data
        if(count($datahijo)>0){array_push($data,$datahijo);}
        //... se reinician variables
        $contadorCompra=1;              
        $datahijo = array();
        $datahijo["Cliente"] = $rowLimpia[$i]['Cliente'];
        $datahijo[$contadorCompra."_Compra"] = $rowLimpia[$i]['Fecha'];
    }       
    $contadorCompra++;
}
//se agrega el ultimo Cliente encontrado al array $data.
if(count($datahijo)>0){array_push($data,$datahijo);}
//probando
var_dump($data);
```

Luego quedan registros con Datos: Cliente, 1ºCompra, 2ºCompra, ...

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Ordenados de esta manera solo te quedara mandarlos al excel directamente:

```
$filaInicial=1;
$columnas = ["","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H"];
$columnaInicial=2;//equivalente a "B" segun $columnas;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
    //pintando Cliente
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$filaInicial, $data[$i]["Cliente"]);
    for($j=1;$j<count($data[$i]);$j++){
        //pintando Compras
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue($columnaInicial.$filaInicial, $data[$i][$j."_Cliente"]);
    }
    $filaInicial++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un ciclo mientras obtengas registros. Cuando el id del cliente sea diferente al anterior agregas información a la primera columna y reinicias el índice de la columna en donde deberá empezar a poner las compras del usuario.

```
$resource=$mysqli->query("select id, cliente,accion,fecha... where accion='compra'");
$id=0;
$linea=3;
while($row=$resource->fetch_array()){
    if($id!=$row[0]){
         $linea++; 
         $libro->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $linea)->setValue($row[1]);
         $columna=1;
    }
    $libro->getActiveSheet()->getCellByColumnAndRow($columna, $linea)->setValue($row[2]);
    $columna++;
}
```

Solo lo hice para compras por que para Ventas no mencionas que habría que hacer.

Comment: Entiendo, creo que me puede servir, el lunes lo pruebo, y comento que tal. Que no tengo el código en mi pc. 
Muchas gracias. 
Un saludo!!